# Different NIntegrate results for the same formula

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

What I do is `Integrate` a formula and then `NItegrate` the output of the previous integration. The problem is I get different `NItegrate` results depending on whether I copy the `Integrate` output manually or put it as a defined variable.

The formula is

```
(0.0232723 kx Sin[3.2 kx])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2)*
 (0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2))
```

First I do the `Integrate`

```
f = Assuming[{kz ∈ Reals && kz != 0 && kx ∈ Reals && ky ∈ Reals}, 
Integrate[(0.0232723 kx Sin[3.2 kx])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2)*
 (0.0232723 + kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2)), {ky, -∞, ∞}, {kz, -∞, ∞}]]
```

where the output is

> `` (845.3256946557052 kx ((0. + 0.060962518629646675 I) Log[1. - (0. + 0.0014188019531818545 I)/Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456`*^-6 + 1. kx^2]] - (0. + 0.060962518629646675 I) Log[1. + (0. + 0.0014188019531818545 I)/ Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456*^-6 + 1. kx^2]] - (0. + 0.060962518629646675 I) Log[1. - (0. + 0.15255934980455418 I)/Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456*^-6 + 1. kx^2]] + (0. + 0.060962518629646675 I) Log[1. + (0. + 0.15255934980455418 I)/Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456*^-6 + 1. kx^2]]) Sin[3.2 kx])/(Sqrt[-0.023272342213805974 + 11561.030292527505 kx^2]) ``

Now onto the `NIntegrate`. I can either do

```
NIntegrate[f, {kx, -∞, ∞}]
```

and get

> -47.0578 + 0. I

or copy the `Integrate` output manually and do

```
NIntegrate[(845.3256946557052` kx ((0.` + 0.060962518629646675` I) Log[1.` - (0.` + 0.0014188019531818545` I)/
 Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456`*^-6 + 1.` kx^2]] - (0.` + 0.060962518629646675` I) Log[1.` + (0.` + 0.0014188019531818545` I)/
 Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456`*^-6 + 1.` kx^2]] - (0.` + 0.060962518629646675` I) Log[1.` - (0.` + 0.15255934980455418` I)/
 Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456`*^-6 + 1.` kx^2]] + (0.` + 0.060962518629646675` I) Log[1.` + (0.` + 0.15255934980455418` I)/
 Sqrt[-2.0129989823526456`*^-6 + 1.` kx^2]]) Sin[3.2` kx])/(Sqrt[-0.023272342213805974` + 11561.030292527505` kx^2]), 
 {kx, -∞, ∞}]
```

This gives

> -0.359278 + 0. I

Why are the results different and how can I know which is the correct one?

P.S.
The results include imaginary numbers even though I wrote assumptions that $kx$, $ky$, $kz$ are real, I don't know why the results are still with `I`.

Comment: In V13.3.0 (Mac ARM) I get `-0.359278` for the integral of `f`, the output copied from my notebook, and the posted output above.

Answer (score 2):

If you `Rationalize`the integrand first it's possible to `Integrate` along `ky,kz`

```
expr = Rationalize[(0.0232723 kx Sin[3.2 kx])/((-kx^2 - ky^2 - 0.00008649 kz^2)*(0.0232723 + kx^2 +ky^2 + kz^2)), 0]
```

$\frac{232723 \text{kx} \sin \left(\frac{16 \text{kx}}{5}\right)}{10000000 \left(-\text{kx}^2-\text{ky}^2-\frac{8649
   \text{kz}^2}{100000000}\right) \left(\text{kx}^2+\text{ky}^2+\text{kz}^2+\frac{232723}{10000000}\right)}$

```
intyz = Integrate[expr , {ky, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]} , {kz, -\[Infinity], \\[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {Element[{kx }, Reals], kx > 0}]
```

[image]

Result shows a restriction `kx > (93 Sqrt[232723/999913510])/1000` which indicates that further integration `-Infinity<kx<Infinity` isn't possible!

**addendum**

If we ignore these restrictions (there is a removable singularity at `kx == \[PlusMinus](93 Sqrt[232723/999913510])/1000`) we get (without message)

```
NIntegrate[intyz[[1]], {kx, -Infinity, Infinity} ]
(*-0.359278*)
```

Knowing the singularities we can "confirm" this result

```
NIntegrate[expr, {kx, -Infinity, Infinity}, {ky,Infinity,Infinity},{kz, -Infinity, Infinity} , 
Method -> "PrincipalValue",Exclusions -> {kx == -((93Sqrt[232723/999913510])/1000), kx == (93 Sqrt[232723/999913510])/1000 }]   
(*-0.358437*)
```

Last result gives a message `...error estimate 0.010923508468859621`

Hope it helps!

Comment: You made an assumption that `kx > 0` while it can vary from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Without your assumption the condition is `kx > (93 Sqrt[232723/999913510])/1000 || kx < -((93 Sqrt[232723/999913510])/1000)` or `kx > 0.0014188 || kx < -0.0014188` which in my opinion is acceptable as it's a small range that can be skipped without the loss of precision. So in my understanding further `NIntegrate` should still be possible in the $-\infty<kx<\infty$ range. I guess some exception for the `kx > 0.0014188 || kx < -0.0014188` condition should be manually put in the formula? But I don't know how.

Comment: @Patrycja  Integral is symmetric in `kx` , though try `NIntegrate[intyz,{kx,0.0014188,Infinity}]`. But I don't know how to estimate the integration error.

Comment: In this case the problem is still the same - whether I put `intyz` into the `NIntegrate` or its explicit form I get two very different results, -46.8549 and 0.535058 respectively, with the explicit form giving the following error `DoubleExponentialOscillatory has failed to converge for the integrand`.

Comment: @Patrycja "DoubleExponentialOscillatory has failed to converge for the integrand" is not an error, it is a warning. :) Try the same integrand with different method.